# Problem with ionic/vue router animation bleeds

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, vue-router

I'm building an ionic/vue app and I'm having a problem with the animation on logout. Animation stutters when moving from the main page to the authorization page

I think problem in router

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svSjT.png)

```
 const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: '/auth',
    name: 'auth',
    component: FeatureAuthByLoginAndPassword,
    meta: {
      middleware: [guest],
    },
  },
  {
    path: '/pinCode',
    name: 'pinCode',
    component: FeatureAuthByPinCode,
    meta: {
      middleware: [pincode],
    },
  },
  {
    path: '/',
    redirect: '/tabs/tab1',
  },
  {
    path: '/tabs/',
    component: TabsPage,
    meta: {
      middleware: [auth],
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirect: 'tab1',
      },
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        component: () => import('@/pages/ActiveClaimsList.vue'),
      },
      {
        path: 'tab2',
        component: () => import('@/pages/AllClaimList.vue'),
      },
      {
        path: 'tab3',
        component: () => import('@/pages/ClaimsHistory.vue'),
      },
    ],
  },
```

this is how my routes look like

I logout from TabsPage to PinCodePage

```
    const signOut = () => {
      logout();
      router.replace('/pinCode');
    };
```

Comment: "The answer to the ultimate question of life, the universe, and everything is... 42." - **Share enough source code so that we can see what you did and where improvements could be made.** Otherwise, at first glance, there seems to be **no background for the component (?)** that you raised towards everything.

Comment: @rozsazoltan could check please

Comment: Is the content of the `FeatureAuthByPinCode` component associated with the `pinCode`  Route visible in the attached photo? If yes, then the code attachment should be associated from there, as that is where the root cause of the problem will be found.

Comment: Try `this.$router.push` instead of `this.$router.replace`. The browser maybe can cause interference, as using the "replace" function does not open a new page, but deletes the current one and replaces it with the new requested content. If the error persists when using the `push` method, then the cause of the problem should not be sought here. --- Or if you need use `replace`, then you can turn off browser cache: `inhibitCache: true` in Route's meta.

Comment: I found a bug. The reason was that the background of my page was transparent because of this, it seemed like the animation was hanging. I set the background of the page to white and everything started working fine. @rozsazoltan thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IMPORTANT**: In my response, I am not familiar with the source code shown in the picture, so I can only assume that the intended purpose is to display a PIN pad (`FeatureAuthByPinCode`) in the foreground, while the content visible in the background is the previous route's content (`TabsPage`) that should not be displayed anymore.

---

#### Vue-Router: `replace()`

- not send a new request
- just replaces the current content with the next
- no record of it is made in the browser history
- back button loses its function (that would be the goal if you use replace)
- possible that due to caching, the content of the previous page remains visible (this is not the fault of the page, but of the browser)

#### Vue-Router: `push()`

- new entry is added to the browser history
- definitely does not interfere with the cache
- can use back button

#### Vue-Router: How to can disable current page cache on browser?

Use `inhibitCache: true` in meta.

This can be helpful in cases where the page's content needs to be updated frequently without relying on the browser's cache. (maybe with `replace()` using)

```js
const routes = [
  // ...
  {
    path: '/about',
    component: ExampleAbout,
    meta: {
      // disable cache on about route
      inhibitCache: true
    }
  },
  // ...
]
```